# Email sent upon Login in Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, login

Is it possible to configure in Windows Server 2008 to have an email sent to a specified address when a specific user account has successfully logged in? We want to be notified of when a particular user's account has logged in for a specific security purpose and need to be made aware right  away.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A logon script is the way.  We currently do this for a number of user accounts we consider "sensitive" (admins in other words) as well as anybody logging on to a server.

Answer (score 0):

You can put his account in its own OU and apply a login script that could notify you either via email or another means.

Answer (score 0):

Logon scripts are certainly the way to go for this kind of thing. I use a standard script that everyone runs but near the end of that script it looks for a script with the user's logon name as the base filename (e.g. jgardeniers.vbs). If it exists then it is called for user specific processing. Otherwise the main script exits normally. Over the years I've found this to be the easiest way to handle special cases. Of course the same could be used for groups.